# ByteBuddy - create Interface of getter/setter's

Tags: byte-buddy

I am trying to generate an Intgerface from a List, where the elements represent 'get' methods.  The Interface is generated without Exception, but when I reflectively try to get the methods of the Interface of the Dynamic type, there are no Methods listed.  This seems like it ought to be a simple thing to do

```
ByteBuddy bb = new ByteBuddy();
Builder<?> bbb = bb.makeInterface().merge(Visibility.PUBLIC);
for (K name : propertyNames) {
    String get = "get" + name.toString();
    String set = "set" + name.toString();
    bbb.defineMethod(get, String.class, Visibility.PUBLIC); //** .withoutCode()
    bbb.defineMethod(set, String.class, Visibility.PUBLIC).withParameter(String.class); //** .withoutCode()
}
DynamicType.Unloaded unloadedType = bbb.name(NAME).make();
DYNAMIC_TYPE = unloadedType.load(POJOFactory.class.getClassLoader()).getLoaded();
```

I have google searched over the past week looking for references to creating an Interface with ByteBuddy, but there simply arent any references.

Thanks,

Comment: I figured out the issue. The issue was the way in which I was referring to the 'bbb' reference.  The currect usage is:  "bbb = bbb.defineMethod....".  I needed to store the result back into the original reference after the method call.

Answer (score 0):

Byte Buddy's builder API is fully immutable. You have to always operate on the return value. All calls are side-effect free so doing:

```
builder.<something>
```

has no effect. The correct way would be to:

```
builder = builder.<something>
```